# If execv launches a process using "/bin/sh -c", will there be a new process?

Tags: c, shell, exec

I want execute another program in C program. Since I want use redirection, I use *execl* function to execute /bin/sh and pass the new command to it. Code is like this:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/myprogram > a.out", NULL);
```

I know C program process will turn to be the shell(/bin/sh) process in the first stage. What confuses me is that whether the new shell process **forks a new process to execute "/myprogram > a.out"** or **the shell process itself parses and turns to be "/myprogram  > a.out"**.

I did a small test on this. Result seems to support the latter hypothesis. Test is like this:

1. I start a zsh on my computer, run the command `echo $$`, result is `56341`. This shell's pid is 56341

   ```
   $ echo $$
   56341
   ```
2. Then run command `/bin/sh -c "/Users/Jack/dead_loop"` in this shell. It does not return because the program is a forever loop.

   ```
   $ /bin/sh -c "/Users/Jack/dead_loop"
   █
   ```

   The dead_loop source code is:

   ```
   int main(){
       while(1){
           ;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I start a new terminal and run command `ps -ef|grep dead_loop`. Result shows that the `dead_loop` program's parent process is the first shell process.

   [image]

What I expect is that the `dead_loop` program's parent process is another new shell process. So this "the shell process itself parses and turns to be `/myprogram > a.out`" idea comes to my mind.

Comment: The shell will create a new process for `/myprogram`. You could implement the redirection in your C program as well, then you would not need the shell. (see `dup2` or `dup`)

Comment: Since a shell itself can not run binary code, it has no choice other then doing a fork. But if you would do a `"exec /myprogram"`, it would **replace** itself by a new process running  `/myprogram` and no child process would be created.

Comment: I believe some shells implement an optimization where they also exec themselves and do not spawn a child, but you certainly shouldn't rely on that.  If you need to ensure that there is no intermediate process, just do the redirection yourself.  Implementing that would be a good exercise.  (It's fairly easy.)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the `exec` family of functions *replaces* the current process.

You must use `fork` to create a new process to run `exec` (if you want your program to continue).

And it's the same for the shell: It must also `fork` a new process to call `exec` for the programs it runs.

Comment: I updated my problem with a small test that may disagree with your opinion.

Comment: @jack There is a comment by William Pursell (to your question) which explains what is going on. Your test does pretty well contradict this answer, but it does nothing to support the conclusion you draw (which is incorrect). The two possible mechanisms you mention are not exhaustive. There is a third possibility, which is the one William mentions.